# d3.csv returning each row instead of an array

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am totally beginner in D3 and i've trying to make some graphs of an external dataset. I've choose a [Premier League Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/zaeemnalla/premier-league), but when i call d3.csv to create an array with all data, the function returns to me each row instead of the entire dataset. What is wrong with my code?

OBS: Sorry for the bad english

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="bar-chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
let height = 400;
let width = 1000;
let svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("width", width);

d3.csv("../Datasets/results.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

[Console after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y79v9.png)

Comment: You're using D3 v7. It should be `d3.csv("../Datasets/results.csv").then( function(data) { etc...`.